# How to include all associations when creating and merging a version in Shopware DAL?

Tags: version, shopware6

When I edit the order in the admin, a version is created. I get a version clone commit for each order table. Now I found an entity with an association to an order that is not part of the clone. I noticed that the relation from that entity to the order is version aware but the entity itself is not version aware. Do I need to make it version aware as well so the order clone and later merge works? Because right now the merge is broken due to FK issues and I assume it misses a clone in the first place.

TL:DR; what are important parts in entity definitions to check when one want to support order editing in admin (which triggers version create and merge)?

Here is the entity definition in question that somehow is not part of version cloning of orders:

```php
(new IdField('id', 'id'))->addFlags(new ApiAware(), new PrimaryKey(), new Required()),

(new FkField('order_id', 'orderId', OrderDefinition::class))->addFlags(new ApiAware(), new Required()),
(new ReferenceVersionField(OrderDefinition::class, 'order_version_id'))->addFlags(new ApiAware(), new Required()),

// ... entity content
(new CustomFields())->addFlags(new ApiAware()),


(new ManyToOneAssociationField('order', 'order_id', OrderDefinition::class, 'id', false))->addFlags(new ApiAware()),
```

Answer (score 1):

#### Updated possible cause

Did you also extend the `OrderDefinition` to add the association on that side?

```php
(new OneToManyAssociationField('customEntities', CustomEntityDefinition::class, 'order_id'))->addFlags(new ApiAware(), new CascadeDelete())
```

That would explain why it's ignored in the clone process.

Solution update: The `OneToManyAssociationField` **must** have the `CascadeDelete` flag or else it won't be used as an association to be cloned.

#### Old answer (regarding m2m relations, not the case here)

Yes, you need to make the associations version aware. Otherwise you'd run into conflicts with foreign key constraints.

Let's say in case of a regular many-to-many relation you'd have the columns `order_id` and `my_entity_id` for the mapping. The combination of those two would form a unique constraint.

In your case you'd need to make the `MappingEntityDefinition` version aware and add a `ReferenceVersionField` for the `order` relation. So to allow version aware associations you'd instead need the columns `order_id`, `order_version_id` and `my_entity_id`. These would then form the unique constraint and allow to create versions with the associations intact.

Comment: This is familiar to me and should already be present on that entity. One of the basics that definitely have to be check, right. Sorry that I did not make it clear in my question. I will amend it. It is about a one-to-many and the reference to order is already version aware, but not the entity it is linked to.

Comment: I see. The definition you set as reference for your `OneToManyAssociationField` in the order is versionized but that definition has it's own associations and they are left out/cause problems, correct? What kind of associations does it have? If it has *-to-many associations I could see the problem. Then the problem described in the answer still applies and then you would have to make the definitions related on a second level version aware as well.

Comment: I see you added the definition of the entity that fails to be cloned. Just to clarify, did you also extend the `OrderDefinition` to add the association on that side? `new OneToManyAssociationField('customEntities', CustomEntityDefinition::class, 'order_id')` - that would explain why it's ignored in the clone process.

Comment: Yes, I can load the data via association from the order.repository. The association works for me in API usage. Just does not get cloned in a version clone